# Is it possible to create website on Drupal that works same as Airbnb?

Tags: drupal

Is it possible to create website on Drupal that works something like Airbnb ?

Specifications:

1. Reserving houses with online calendar and calculation of total sum of reservation.
2. Gallery of houses pictures.
3. Ability to pay with Visa/MasterCard and etc.
   In other words, this website should work as simple hotel website.
   I'd really appreciate if you'd give some examples (hotel websites).

Answer (score 1):

There's an established [hotel booking system](http://drupal.org/project/uc_hotel) that ties into Ubercart.

Looking forward, work is also converging around the [Rooms](http://drupal.org/project/rooms) project, but that's still in dev status.